# How do I count the number of columns in each table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to write a script to listing the tables in my database with the number of columns in that table.

Like this:

```
table name      number       
---------       --------     
table1            1         
table2            13        
table3            2         
table4            6
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can look at columns in [sys.columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106%28v=sql.120%29.aspx):

> Returns a row for each column of an object that has columns, such as views or tables. The following is a list of object types that have columns:

- Table-valued assembly functions (FT)
- Inline table-valued SQL functions (IF)
- Internal tables (IT)
- System tables (S)
- Table-valued SQL functions (TF)
- User tables (U)
- Views (V)

For columns count in tables, this query can be used:

```
SELECT [Schema] = s.name
    , [Table] = t.name
    , number = COUNT(*)
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
GROUP BY t.name, s.name
```

- [sys.tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) can be replaced by [sys.views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190334%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) for count in views
- [sys.objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) can also be used with a `WHERE` clause on required type(s):

  ```
  SELECT [Schema] = s.name
      , [Table] = o.name
      , number = COUNT(*)
      , o.type_desc
  FROM sys.columns c
  INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON c.object_id = o.object_id
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
  WHERE type IN (
      'U'     --> U = Table (user-defined)
      , 'V'   --> V = View
      , ...) 
  GROUP BY o.name, s.name, o.type_desc;
  ```

---

This would work too although it is preferable (read [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views) from Aaron Bertrand) to use the first query:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA
    , TABLE_NAME
    , number = COUNT(*) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select st.name, count(1) as column_count 
from sys.tables st
inner join sys.columns sc on st.object_id = sc.object_id
where st.name like '%%'
group by st.name
order by count(1) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'TBlName'

Thats Enough to Get a number of columns that we have in to our Table

Its only for One table

Comment: Your answer should consider CATALOG and SCHEMA too.